# JIRA. Issues transferring

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

How I can Export all issues with Content, Comment and other fields and Import to other JIRA Project, which based in other server?

I am tried Export to CSV file and Import to other, but in this case I'm losting a:

1) Comments of Issue is not exporting to CSV file

2) Attachment images is not transferring at correctly

Answer (score 1):

In jira6 (perhaps earlier versions as well), in the administration menu click `System`. On the left side you'll find `Import & Export`. Use `Backup system` to export to xml, and `Restore System` to import the xml. It will export all comments and configuration except for attachments. This needs to be done manually.

Comment: Good way, but in first server i don't have a Administrator roles

Comment: If you have read access, you can write a script to read all issues via REST api, and store them in a way which you can later import. A quick search in google did not yield anything relevant and it may be a bit tedious, but I don't know any other way without admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV exported from JIRA is not intended to be suitable for use by the JIRA CSV importer.

Answer (score 0):

There are add-ons (paid) that can export comments and attachments:

**Better Excel** can do comments and worklogs

**JExcel Pro** can do comments and attachments